# Read of types sum

Tags: haskell

When I want to read string to type A I write `read str::A`. Consider, I want to have generic function which can read string to different types, so I want to write something like `read str::A|||B|||C` or something similar. The only thing I could think of is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
infixr 9 |||
data a ||| b = A a|B b deriving Show
-- OR THIS:
-- data a ||| b = N | A a (a ||| b) | B b (a ||| b) deriving (Data, Show)

instance (Read a, Read b) => Read (a ||| b) where
  readPrec = parens $ do
    a <- (A <$> readPrec) <|> (B <$> readPrec)
    -- OR:
    -- a <- (flip A N <$> readPrec) <|> (flip B N <$> readPrec)
    return a
```

And if I want to read something:

```
> read "'a'"::Int|||Char|||String
B (A 'a')
```

But what to do with such weird type? I want to fold it to `Int` or to `Char` or to `String`... Or to something another but "atomic" (scalar/simple). Final goal is to read strings like `"1,'a'"` to list-like `[D 1, D 'a']`. And main constraint here is that structure is flexible, so string can be `"1, 'a'"` or `"'a', 1"` or `"\"xxx\", 1, 2, 'a'"`. I know how to read something separated with delimiter, but this something should be passed as type, not as sum of types like `C Char|I Int|S String|etc`. Is it possible? Or no way to accomplish it without sum of types?

Comment: If your data can be one of many types (Char or Int or String, etc) then yes, there is no way to represent it without a sum type. Your type `|||` is just `Either` (from `Data.Either`) which is a very standard type (not that weird) - see that module to how to deconstruct an `Either` (and likewise your `|||`). Note: the 'alternate' definition is just `[Either a b]`.

Comment: `Either` is parameterized by only 2 types, which means that I can read strings into one of 2 types. But I need to read string into N different types, not 2. I can use something like `read s::A|||B|||C|||D|||E`. If I'll re-write standard `Read` instance of `Either` I'll can to read `s` to `A` or to `B` and never to `C`, `D` and etc...

Comment: `A ||| B ||| C` is just nested applications of `|||` - it is `(|||) A ((|||) B C)`. The same exact thing can be accomplished with `Either` - `Either A (Either B C)`. If you need a custom `Read` instance (as you do in your case), then declaring a new (isomorphic) type or using a newtype are the way to go. But my understanding is your question is primarily this: "I want to fold it to Int or to Char or to String" - in which case, you can deconstruct `|||` exactly the same ways as `Either`, regardless of the `Read` instances.

Comment: Exactly, this is what I don't know how to do: how to deconstruct such nested/recursive type. I can get `A 1` or `A (B 'a')` or `B (B (A (B 1)))` and so on, and how to match it - all those expressions have different types

Comment: The types should not be different; that is the point of a sum type. Indeed, the term `[ A 1, A (B 'a'), B (B (A (B 1))) ]` is well-typed (except for the fact that it requires a `Num (a ||| Char)` instance, which arises from the fact that the inferred type is not strictly right-nested). If you really want, you can have a 'true' n-ary sum, e.g. `data Sum (xs :: [*]) where { A :: x -> Sum (x : xs) ; B :: Sum xs -> Sum (x : xs) }`

Comment: I wasn't exact: I need generic read function which can be called with different signatures (like standard `read`), for example: `read _::Int ||| Char` or `read _::Char|||String|||Int`. And some another function which will "fold" such `a|||b` to something simple: `m a`, `m b`. This folding function will work with values of types like `Int ||| Char`, `Char ||| String ||| Int` and similar, so how it can be generic and process all kinds of such types? This is what I mean "different types": folding function arg will have flex type/structure of common form `a ||| b`. Excuse me if I was not exact

Comment: You can already call `read` in such a way at different types with your `Read` instances; the issue, as I see it, is only in how to deconstruct your type, which depends entirely on *what* you wish to do. E.g., if you want to deconstruct a sum `a ||| b` into a `String` by `show`ing each variant, you must have a `Show` instance for `a` and `b` (this is exactly how the derived `Show` instance works). In general, to have a function `a ||| b -> X` you need two functions `a -> X` and `b -> X` (indeed, there is `either :: (a -> x) -> (b -> x) -> (Either a b -> x)` - implement yours the same way)

Comment: I'd like to offer a different opinion than the above: you should rethink your plan. The plan you have in mind is doable but very unidiomatic in Haskell, in part because Haskell does *not* support it very well at all. There will be a bunch of extra noise in your code compared to a more idiomatic solution. (I would also say it is unidiomatic in part because it is an error-prone way to design software.) But I can't offer an alternative given only the few details described here -- there are many possible design fixes depending on what's wanted.

Comment: Seems I need to patter-match on type-level, bcz `a` in `(a->x)` (1st `either` arg) can be any: `A _`/`A (A _)`/`B (A (B _))` and so on. All of them have diff. types. I check src of HSet/HVec but they looks very difficult to me. @DanielWagner: seems you are right, may be I need another solution.

Comment: @Paul-AG, you are basically writing a parser.  You could just embrace that and define an AST, a parser into it, and an evaluation function out of it.  What do you want to do with the result?

Comment: Result should be collection (list): tags. And I will match/check existent of tag in this collection. I have collection, have matching, has different types (one per tag type) and show list of tags as "tag1,tag2,tag2". But when I'll read it, I need to specify returned type, so I think about something like those `|||` (or `Either`)...

Answer (score 2):

There’s no way to do this **in general** using `read`, because the same input string might parse correctly to more than one of the valid types.  You could, however, do this with a function like `Text.Read.readMaybe`, which returns `Nothing` on ambiguous input.  You might also return a tuple or list of the valid interpretations, or have a rule for which order to attempt to parse the types in, such as: attempt to parse each type in the order they were declared.

Here’s some example code, as proof of concept:

```
import Data.Maybe (catMaybes, fromJust, isJust, isNothing)
import qualified Text.Read

data AnyOf3 a b c = FirstOf3 a | SecondOf3 b | ThirdOf3 c

instance (Show a, Show b, Show c) => Show (AnyOf3 a b c) where
  show (FirstOf3 x) = show x -- Can infer the type from the pattern guard.
  show (SecondOf3 x) = show x
  show (ThirdOf3 x) = show x

main :: IO ()
main =
 (putStrLn . unwords . map show . catMaybes . map readDBS)
   ["True", "2", "\"foo\"", "bar"] >>
 (putStrLn . unwords . map show . readIID) "100"

readMaybe' :: (Read a, Read b, Read c) => String -> Maybe (AnyOf3 a b c)
-- Based on the function from Text.Read
readMaybe' x | isJust a && isNothing b && isNothing c =
  (Just . FirstOf3 . fromJust) a -- Can infer the type of a from this.
             | isNothing a && isJust b && isNothing c =
  (Just . SecondOf3 . fromJust) b -- Can infer the type of b from this.
             | isNothing a && isNothing b && isJust c =
  (Just . ThirdOf3 . fromJust) c -- Can infer the type of c from this.
             | otherwise                              = Nothing
  where a = Text.Read.readMaybe x
        b = Text.Read.readMaybe x
        c = Text.Read.readMaybe x

readDBS :: String -> Maybe (AnyOf3 Double Bool String)
readDBS = readMaybe'

readToList :: (Read a, Read b, Read c) => String -> [AnyOf3 a b c]
readToList x = repack FirstOf3 x ++ repack SecondOf3 x ++ repack ThirdOf3 x
  where repack constructor y | isJust z  = [(constructor . fromJust) z]
                             | otherwise = []
          where z = Text.Read.readMaybe y

readIID :: String -> [AnyOf3 Int Integer Double]
readIID = readToList
```

The first output line echoes every input that parsed successfully, that is, the Boolean constant, the number and the quoted string, but not `bar`.  The second output line echoes every possible interpretation of the input, that is, 100 as an `Int`, an `Integer` and a `Double`.

For something more complicated, you want to write a parser.  Haskell has some very good libraries to build them out of combinators.  You might look at one such as Parsec.  But it’s still helpful to understand what goes on under the hood.

Comment: Yes, I thought about such solution, but trick here is that this "read" function must be generic: client of the library may want to read different types' sums: `AnyOf3` of something else. It must be function which can read one of N types. So, I thought: usually it's not possible, but if client will pass type? So, I wrote those `|||` operator which allows client to specify what exactly types can be read from the string. But this does not help, because Haskell hasn't simple way to match/fold such types. Type-level lists? But I'm not familiar w/ such things

Comment: It's like to write "read" which parses only Int's or Int either Char. OK, but how to write generic "read" which can parse one of N types, and those N-types are specified by client, so can be absolutely any.

Comment: so main question in your solution is: how to avoid hardcoded constructors of `AnyOf3` and `AnyOf3` itself. It must be some type which can be traversable and each item is type, so I can to pattern-match on one of them, then on another one, etc...

Comment: Hm, I done Eq for `|||`, so I need only some wildcard to equal any `a|||b` with it. So, parsed type will be `a|||b` and I will not extract something from `a|||b`. Looks like, parsed result is elem of set `a|||b|||...` <- this is the type of tags set and tag itself ("tag" is a parse result from str like "tag1,tag2,..."). Not good is only that `a|||b` != `b|||a`.

Comment: @Paul-AG The way to get any number of types would be, I suppose, nested `Either`, e.g. `Either a (Either b c)`, but it would be very easy to extend any of those functions to two, four or any other number of alternatives.  The solution I posted *does* allow `a`, `b` and `c` to be any completely generic types.

Comment: However,  @user2407038 made the suggestion of nested binary infix TypeOperators, which I think is on the right track for what you want.