# How to match such type

Tags: haskell

I have:

```
infixr 9 |||
data a ||| b = A a|B b deriving (Eq, Data, Show)

class IsTag a where
  anyTag :: a
```

and I keep in this `a|||b` some values, which are instances of `IsTag`, for example: `A (B (A x))` - the deep of nesting can be any, sure. And I want to write function which detects that `x` is equal to `anyTag`, so it takes `a|||b` and returns `Bool` - is underlying value (`x` in the example) equal to `anyTag` of x's instance or not. How to write such function? I can't do pattern-matching due to errors like "infinite type", etc. I added `deriving Data` to `a|||b` and to x's type in the hope that it will be possible to use something from `Data`, but I can't understand how to fold/traverse via such recursive type.

Comment: Could you add a minimal, complete example of the kind of code you want to be able to write? It’ll help illustrate the actual problem you’re trying to solve.

Comment: [Begin of journey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47577470/read-of-types-sum). This is a tags combining from different types w/ generic read/match/show. All is good and task is solved but I hit that I need to distinguish cases when tag matched tags like [tag1,tag2] and [tag1,anyTag] (this is pseudo-code) - to know best matching case (more specialized/general case). So, I need to check that tag type (`a|||b`) keeps something which is `==anyTag`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't get much better than this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
class IsAnyTag a where
    isAnyTag :: a -> Bool
    default isAnyTag :: (Eq a, IsTag a) => a -> Bool
    isAnyTag = (anyTag ==)

instance (IsAnyTag a, IsAnyTag b) => IsAnyTag (a ||| b) where
    isAnyTag (A a) = isAnyTag a
    isAnyTag (B b) = isAnyTag b

-- and one more line of `instance IsAnyTag X` for each `X` that
-- is an instance of `IsTag`
```

The main drawback here is that this requires that the types on both sides of the `|||` will have to be `IsAnyTag` instances, even though you are testing only one side. Them's the breaks with static type checking.